# RSelenium Selenium server signals port = 4567 is already in use

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I'm trying to run a simple RSelenium script to scrape the web, but I'm getting an error `Selenium server signals port = 4567 is already in use`. Steps:

First I start the driver in the terminal: `$ docker run -d -p 4567:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome`

I can see it's up and running with `docker ps`

In RStudio I try running:

```
library(RSelenium)
remDrAll <- rsDriver(port = 4567L, browser = "chrome")
```

but I get an error that says the port is already in use (described above). I've ran this 1000s of times and I was just running the same code a day ago and it was working just fine.

When I run `$ lsof -nP -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN` there's nothing out of the ordinary.

I'm sorry I can't give reproducible code, but I'm at a loss here. Can anyone help me figure out why I can't connect?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the approach described [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991498/rselenium-server-signals-port-is-already-in-use) It mainly uses

```
library(RSelenium)
remDrAll <- rsDriver(port = 4567L, browser = "chrome")
remDr <- remDrAll$client
remDr$close()
rm(remDrAll )
gc()
```

I see this is only a partial solution, though: I tried a few times and it only works some of the them. In the others I had to close and reopen R.